# Insert subview above inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

My problem is this:
I have a UIViewController with an input accessory view:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController  {
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
        get { return customToolbar }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to add a subview above that inputAccessoryView, something like this:

```
let customView = UIView()
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.view.insertSubview(customView, aboveSubview: self.inputAccessoryView)
```

But for some reasons, the inputAccessoryView is always on top.

I have thought of hiding it each time i want to add a subview (full screen for instance), but this is not super clean, and I'd have to put it back each time i remove my subview.

Here's what I have right now, I just want my toolbar to be behind the transparent overlay.

[image]

Comment: What about just using view.addSubview(customView) where view is the accessoryView

Comment: @rMickeyD well there's no link between those views. I don't want it to move with the inputAccessoryView for instance. Basically i just want to add on overlay to my `ChatViewController` full screen.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot example?

Comment: @rMickeyD just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add your transparent overlay to keyWindow in the Objective-C it's look like

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject] addSubview :customView];
```

Comment: Try that [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject] addSubview:customView]; Before translate to swift. I have already checked it, It's work